# Mysql between dates is not working

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm writing the below query to get records between two dates. I'm using `Mysql` version `5.5`. May its duplicate exactly I didn't know. But no answer working for me so that I'm asking. I'm following least date after latest date. Even though its not working.

**Problem:** Empty resultset.

```
pstmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT urlid FROM youtubevideos WHERE lastwatched >=? AND lastwatched <=? order by id desc LIMIT 8");
pstmt.setString(1,previousdate);//14-05-2015
pstmt.setString(2,currentdate);//12-08-2015
rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
  .........
}
```

But I'm getting empty resultset.

My table `youtubevideos` contains records

```
  urlid   lastwatched
  -------------------
  url1    12-08-2015
  url2    11-08-2015
  url3    08-05-2015
  url4    
  url5    10-08-2015
```

Above is some data. Here `lastwatched` is of `varchar` and `lastwatched` is empty for some records. If my previous date `08-05-2015` means less than the current day (12) then above query working. Otherwise (from 13-05-2015 onwards) its not working. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Can you echo your query and see how it looks. May be values have been interchanged to wrong places.

Comment: how are your date fields defined? if you use the query directly at the database it works?

Comment: @JordiCastilla no its not working. same empty result. my date is of `varchar`.

Comment: Looks like a java problem; setting the 2 values - if I had to guess I think you're getting them backwards and that's why you get that output. I'm sure if you run the SELECT and hard code in the from to dates it will most certainly work - I use it every day (BETWEEN, not >=). Good luck

Comment: Can't you just pass Dates rate than Strings?

Comment: so problem is in your query, not in the prepared statement... review it until it works @ database administrator and then, prepare your statement. This works in mysql `SELECT * FROM your_table where DATE <= "2015-03-09" AND DATE >= "2014-03-09"`

Comment: doesnt mysql use an 2015-05-14 date format instead of 14-05-2015 date format?

Comment: If `lastwatched` is a varchar then `BETWEEN` is not going to work correctly. The dates will be ordered alphabetically, not by date.

Comment: i suppose to use like `yyyy-mm-dd` right.

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong date format for sql:

```
12-08-2015 // this is the output format
```

use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead:

```
2015-08-12 // this is the sql store format
```

This query works great in my Mysql database:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table where DATE <= "2015-05-08" AND DATE >= "2015-08-12"
```

To convert your strings:

```
Date initDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String parsedDate = formatter.format(initDate);
```

Comment: but my `lastwatched` column is of `dd-mm-yyyy`. In java Ill change the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: so your database fields are `varchar`, not `datetime`?

Comment: exactly. so i need to alter this table

Answer (score 1):

> Here `lastwatched` is of `varchar`

The issue is that you are storing date fields as type `VARCHAR`. This would work if your date format was `Y-m-d` since sorting this alphabetically is the same as sorting by date.

I recommend you change the `lastwatched` column to be a date type, this will allow the `BETWEEN` to work correctly and will also provide access to the date functions in MySQL.

Comment: while alter table `ALTER TABLE youtubevideos MODIFY lastwatched DATE;` getting error. Is this correct. @Jim

Comment: @Satya You'll need to convert `lastwatched` to a date first, Gordon's answer provides a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the data in the table.  You should not be storing bona fide dates as `varchar()`.  MySQL has a great data type for them, called `date` (or perhaps `datetime`.

Here is one method:

```
alter table youtubevideos add column NEW_lastwatched date;

update youtubevideos
    set NEW_lastwatched = str_to_date(lastwatched, '%d-%m-%Y');

alter table drop column lastwatched;

alter table rename column NEW_lastwatched lastwatched date;
```

Then, pass in your parameters in the ISO standard format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and your problems with dates using this column will be fixed.

Comment: Im getting error here `str_to_date('%d-%m-%Y');` Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'str_to_date'.